# Use a polygon for a reverse cookie cutter

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects, c#

Is there a way using c# or arcpy to use a polygon to cut a 
hole in a database through lines, points, and polygons, like a reverse cookie cutter? 
This is without having to import and export the whole database. Just cut the hole in place in the database.

Comment: In ArcGIS, databases are used to store spatial data. Are you referring to performing the operation without exporting a feature class or shapefile? If so, that's generally not recommended (or possible). Rather, try any of the following commands: 1) Symmetrical Difference, 2) Erase, or 3) Union and then delete the "cookie cutter" features.

Comment: Programming questions are expected to have code.  Once you've started the process it will be easier to figure out what you're intending.